# Looking for 2 keyboard observers. 1 that gets triggered when the keyboard is about to show and 1 that only gets triggered when the keyboard is hiding

Tags: ios, swift

I am mutating a constraint when a keyboard is showing and hiding on the screen so that some text can be displayed at the bottom of the view. I instantiated 2 property observers, `keyboardWillShowNotification` and `keyboardWillHideNotification`. When the app initially starts and I pull up a keyboard, `keyboardWillShowNotification` is triggered as expected, *but* when I hide the keyboard, both `keyboardWillHideNotification` *and* `keyboardWillShowNotification` are triggered which has caused some unexpected behavior with toggling the bottom constraint.

Is there a keyboard observer combo where one observer *only* gets triggered when the keyboard is about to show and the other observer *only* gets triggered when the keyboard is hiding?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default

        notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        print("show")

        }

        notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
        print("hide")

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: You'll need to show some code... preferably a [mre].

Comment: @DonMag, edited with an example

Comment: I just tested your code... I added a tap gesture recognizer to end editing and dismiss the keyboard. I see only `show` when the keyboard appears and `hide` when it disappears... both on an iPhone Device and Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that bug. What I do is bail out of either notification handler if the frame is not actually going to change:

```
let d = notification.userInfo!
let beginning = d[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
let ending = d[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
if beginning == ending {return}
```